# Application Initialization IIS - Log Files

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have configured the Application Initialization for a Web App running on Azure, the reason for that is to improve the "warm up", because I have some issues with Scale-out, the instance is not ready for the connection then I got some servers errors.
There is a good doc from Microsoft about that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

I am not sure how to check if Application Initialization is working.
Are there any logs that I can check?

Comment: I think this document will be helpful to you, please let me know if you have other questions. https://blog.brooksjc.com/2019/06/20/troubleshooting-app-initialization-iis-warmup-on-azure-web-apps/

Comment: http://www.zankavtaskin.com/2016/12/azure-web-app-application-initialization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS doesn’t provide separate log files for each modules and function, but for each website. So application initialization for a web to improve the “warm up”, can be checked by some function.

Advanced Logging is helpful and analyze the log file of the website which applied application initialization module. You can get it from [here](http://%20https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging)

Fail Request Tracing also can help you to trace request when you try to access the website to test whether the initialization is successful, especially using url rewrite with application initialization. Enable fail request tracing from [here.](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)